# Celery worker will not pick up a new task after the current one is finished

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have three tasks:

```
@app.task(name='timey')
def timey():
    print "timey"
    while True:
        pass
    return 1

@app.task(name='endtimey')
def endtimey():
    for i in range(10):
        print "ENDTIMEY", time()
        sleep(3)
    return 1

@app.task(name='nexttask')
def nexttask(n):
    print "NEXT TASK"
    return 1
```

If the only thing I do is chain endtimey and nexttask together -

`chain(endtimey.s() | nexttask.s()).delay()`

everything works as expected.  I see `ENDTIMEY <current time>` print ten times followed by `NEXT TASK` in the celery log.  However, if I fill up 7 of the workers with the infinite task `timey`, and then chain `endtimey` and `nexttask` together -

```
for i in range(7):
    timey.s().delay()
chain(endtimey.s() | nexttask.s()).delay()
```

All the `timey` tasks will be picked up by 7 of the 8 workers, and `endtimey` will run its course on the 8th worker, after which the log will show that `nexttask` has been received, but `nexttask` will not run.

Why is this?

Also, if I kill the celery server and then restart it, `nexttask` will be the first thing to run.

This is a contrived example, but I am having an issue in a more complicated situation where celery workers are not picking up queued tasks once they are finished with their current tasks.  And if I restart celery in that instance, the free workers will begin to pick up tasks again.

Comment: this sounds like a bug, have you filed a bug with celery or do you know of a filed bug?

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure it is a bug.  According to Chris Ward's answer, the issue is that workers reserve tasks ahead of time, so if one of the workers running the infinite task reserves `nexttask.s()`, then it never gets picked up.  It seems like a conscious design decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is celery's default pre-fetch behavior. Each worker will reserve a set number of tasks ahead of time while it is currently at maximum capacity and this is known as the [Prefetch Multiplier](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefetch-limits).

The reason it does that is so that when you have a high volume of short tasks, your overall throughput will be much higher if the tasks are already prefetched and ready to execute immediately.

The problem is that when you have a lot of long running tasks or a mixture of long and short tasks, then tasks can get reserved and blocked up by a busy worker even though other workers are available to handle it.

Therefore, in your case you may need to lower the prefetch multiplier to 1.

Comment: Thanks so much @Chris Saved my day..Ideally celery should put this behaviour very much highlighted in the docs.